# Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric convert/cast

Tags: sql, sql-server, types, casting, type-conversion

I suspect this has to do with reporting `ClientName`, which is a `nvarchar` data type. `AUMid` is `nchar`. I'm not sure how to work around this without changing the data types (which I prefer not to).

```
SELECT 
    Clients.ClientName, AUM.ManagementFee, 
    SUM(AUM.ManagementFee * AUM.AUM) AS Management_Fee
FROM
    AUM
JOIN 
    Clients ON AUM.AUMid = Clients.AUMid
GROUP BY 
   Clients.ClientName, AUM.ManagementFee
```

I need to display `Clients.ClientName`. It is linked to the `AUM` table via `AUM.AUMid`.

```
CREATE TABLE Clients 
(
    ClientID nvarchar(50),
    ClientName nvarchar(50)
    AccountID nchar(10),
    AUMid nchar(10)
);

CREATE TABLE AUM
(
    AUMid nchar(10),
    AUM nvarchar(max),
    ManagementFee(decimal(9,4)
);
```

Removing `SUM(AUM.AUM * AUM.ManagementFee) AS Management_Fee` allows the query to execute.

Comment: Please include some sample data.

Comment: AUMid = 1 AUM = 18,431,221.11 ManagementFee = 0.0125 ClientName = Allegany Fire Department

Comment: Do you have any columns which have been defined as text, but which are holding numerical data?

Comment: I do not believe so.

Comment: You should not be seeing this error.

Comment: AUMid is nchar(10) and ClientName is nvarchar(50). I don't know what else could be the problem then.

Comment: @JMBurnworth: "... AUM = 18,431,221.11 ..." -- in one row or in three rows? (It would be better if you edited the question and included the `CREATE` statements for the tables and `INSERT` statements for the sample data to make things clearer. Tagging the DBMS might help too.) If it is in only one row, then you might mean it is the **string** `'18,431,221.11'`. And then the problem might be that you cannot multiply by this string in `SUM(AUM.ManagementFee * AUM.AUM)` as it cannot be converted to a number.

Comment: That is only in one row. I am working on the edit now.

Comment: What happens you you try to execute `select N'18,431,221.11' * 0.0125` in SSMS? Does it say `Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes. SELECT N'18,431,221.11' * 0.0125 results in the same error.

Comment: Well, there are errors in your `CREATE` statements and the `INSERT`s are still missing but I believe [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=6012994457430f44da26e43913e391d5) should represent your situation. As suspected the string value for `aum.aum` is the problem. `aum.aum` seems to be supposed to hold numeric data, so `nvarchar(max)` is certainly not the right type for it. Change the type to some appropriate numeric type and fix the data. See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=611da78f841476af6f90266833fa54a2) how it can look and work.

Comment: As already stated you need to show some sample data and expected results, ideally as DDL/DML statements i.e. a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is clearly causing your error:

```
SUM(AUM.ManagementFee * AUM.AUM) AS Management_Fee
```

because `AUM.AUM` is a string.  That seems like a really bad choice of data types if you want to store a number.  However, I suspect that you really just want a direct sum:

```
SELECT c.ClientName, 
       SUM(a.ManagementFee) AS Management_Fee
FROM Clients c JOIN
     AUM a
     ON a.AUMid = c.AUMid
GROUP BY c.ClientName;
```

On the other hand, the issue may be that `AUM` is a comma-separated list of numbers.  If that is the case, my first and most sincere advice is to fix the data model.  If you cannot do that for some reason, you can parse the string and keep your fingers crossed that it works:

```
SELECT c.ClientName, 
       SUM(a.ManagementFee * TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 6), s.value)) AS Management_Fee
FROM Clients c JOIN
     AUM a
     ON a.AUMid = c.AUMid CROSS APPLY
     string_split(a.aum, ',') s
GROUP BY c.ClientName;
```

Comment: Thanks for saving my hide again, Gordon! I did in fact want to multiply ManagementFee by AUM (Assets Under Management). Although your guidance regarding AUM being a comma-separate list of numbers resolved the issue.

Comment: I see my question received some down-votes. Do you have any advice for me to post better questions? I did attempt to solve it through research and trial/error beforehand, but to no avail. Was it a lack of necessary information to help resolve the problem? Or something else? Any constructive feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @JMBurnworth . . . I don't know why people are so quick to downvote, particularly without giving guidance.  That said, your question would be improved with sample data and desired results in the question.  The actual question needs to be discerned from the original question and the comments.  The question should stand by itself.  (And you can edit the question).

Comment: @JMBurnworth, Gordon has already explained but see [link 1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) & [link 2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)